# All-purpose Technic set?

Tags: technic, sets

For LEGO Classic there are plenty of "build anything" kinds of sets, but is there something like that for Technic?

Ideally, I'm imagining a box of the most useful 1000 or so Technic pieces, so that whenever one wants to build an original (and functional) robot or vehicle, the parts required will most likely be found.

Is there such a set?

I find that most of the Technic sets are specialized for building one specific machine, but after building that, when you want to build something else, the parts are not necessarily all-purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The EV3 expansion set 45560 comes to mind: https://education.lego.com/en-us/products/lego-mindstorms-education-ev3-expansion-set-by-lego-education/45560

[image]

Although intended as a extension to the educational EV3 set, it's mainly technic elements.

Answer (score 6):

There was a Technic sub-theme called Universal that was available mostly in the 1980's. The sets did come with instructions to build as many as 4 different models, but each model rarely used all the parts. The models were more of a demonstration of how to use the parts in interesting ways.

You can browse the sets in the Technic Universal theme here:

https://brickset.com/sets/theme-Technic/subtheme-Universal

Now, because these sets were almost all from the 1980's, they all used studded construction, which is a rarity in modern Technic.

I appreciate that this answer is unlikely to help the original asker, or even anyone else, but I believe it is Technic-ally a correct answer!